# How to import a JSON object from an AWS Lambda Layer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, export, aws-lambda-layers

This may seem simple but I have had a hard time trying to figure it out. I could not seem to find the solution on the web too.

```
//nodejs/models.js:
// City = ...
// ...
module.exports = {City, Country, Coupon, Player, Pollfish, Tree};
```

After zipping nodejs, I uploaded the zip file as an AWS Layer and added the layer to my Lambda function.

When I tried to retrieve the objects in my Lambda function:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const {Player} = require('./models.js');
```

It resulted in an error:

```
2023-01-06T09:19:49.469Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'models.js'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'models.js'","Require stack:","- /var/task/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1000:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"]}
```

So what should be the proper way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you follow this: https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e

Comment: @AnthonyB. Yes, I read that before and managed to import the dependencies. However, I could not import my own objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! It should be:

```
const {Player} = require('/opt/nodejs/models.js');
```